# How to reduce Image file size without losing quality or resolution using php or any other language?

Tags: javascript, java, php, python, image-processing

I have 1 MB HD resolution image. I want file size will be reduce to 50% min (512KB). I have tried it using PHP but it's not working for me. If any one knows please help me.

Like https://tinyjpg.com/ this website.

```
$filename = "image.jpg"; // 1 mb image file
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $width_orig;
$height = $height_orig;

$ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;

if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
 $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
} else {
 $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagejpeg($image_p, "image_resized.jpg", 100);
```

Comment: You want to reduce the image but not the quality or resolution? :/ Forget the process/language, can you elaborate on how that would work?

Comment: If you want a smaller file size, you probably don't want the quality to be 100 in the last line(`imagejpeg($image_p, "image_resized.jpg", 100);`)

Comment: So you want a lossless compression that reduces the size by 50%? Is this what you are asking? Just search for "image format lossless" and try to convert the image to those formats and see if they match the size you want.

Comment: yes, that code is not work for me. so i writes the new and it's working fine. Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

```
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source_url);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
    return $destination_url;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at [Trimage](http://trimage.org/) or [ImageOtim](https://imageoptim.com/). Also, you might try converting the image to a different file format; some formats compress certain types of images better than others.

Unless there's a lot of redundancy in your images, it seems unlikely that you're going to reduce the size by 50% without some loss of information.